# Picom doesn’t not launch with Xfce even after adding it to session and startup

Tags: arch-linux, xfce4

I am on [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) (5.15.13-arch1-1) and [Xfce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce) (xfce4-session 4.16.0 (Xfce 4.16)).

I use the following command to run [Picom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picom), and a similar command works just fine in my autostart script for [XMonad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmonad).

```
picom -b --config ~/.config/xfce/picom/picom.conf --experimental-backends
```

However, creating an entry in session startup doesn’t seem to do anything.

[image]

Comment: Wait, why do you need Picom in xfce? Xfwm4 is already a compositor on its own.

Comment: I know, but I like kawase blur and picom for me is overall a better compositor. Also I have disabled xfce's inbuilt compositor.